# How should I proceed when my employer continually delays my employment contract which was promised months ago?

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, software, employment

I work at a relatively small software company, and have done so for around 6 months. When I landed the job I was told the employment contract would be signed on my first day, and since I have asked the upper management multiple times for a contract. However each time I ask I'm told that it will be done in a month or two, and nothing is ever done about it.

I hate to be one to complain about small things, however at this rate I will have lost a large chunk of workplace pension contribution. It would seem silly to leave my job over such a small detail, but given the number of times I am starting to suspect this may be a deliberate ploy. I'm perfectly happy with my job apart from this, and others seem happy with my progress and contributions.

Is this behaviour typical within the industry? What is the best way of dealing with this situation? Is it worth moving on if other opportunities arise if this keeps happening?

Comment: This isn't a small thing. You shouldn't be working with a contract for both your sake and the sake of your employer. This does not seem like a normal situation to me. Ask, in writing, when you can expect the contract to be delivered. And ask your local labour board what you ought to be doing to get the situation resolved.

Comment: This is a big red flag. 6 months is way too long to be just sloppy organization. This smells like fraud.

Comment: Time to move on

Comment: Please explain 'lost a lot of my workplace pension contribution'. Are they not giving you pension contributions you were expecting?

Comment: How are you being paid? Do you get a proper pension slip that contains your salary paid, your total for this year, taxes deducted, employer tax contributions, NHS contributions? If you don't have that, then they are more than dodgy. Also see https://www.gov.uk/workplace-pensions/what-you-your-employer-and-the-government-pay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your employer is obviously not making the contract available a priority. It doesn't seem to bother your employer that their dilatory approach has cost you a chunk of contributions toward your pension.

I'd say that your employer's failure to keep their word, resulting in avoidable financial damage to you, is or should be a big red flag to you.

You want your employer to comply with the law and with their own policies. It's probably time for you to consider that your contributions will be better appreciated elsewhere.

At your exit interview, make sure to mention the subject of the missing employment contract as a deal killer. You will run over the course of your career into situations where what's important to you is not important to your management. If management acts the way your management does, it's time for you to consider firing them. If that's how your management acts currently toward you, imagine how much less cooperation you'll get from this management if you need something from them and you're no longer working for them. This management is bad news.

Comment: This is simply wrong.Not having a signed contract does not mean you don't get pension contributions, nor is it against the law, nor does it mean you don't have a contract in the legal sense. Leaving is an overreaction. heck with a lawyer if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 7):

Despite the absence of a signed document, if you were told terms and accepted them, and started work, you and your employer have a contract. An employment lawyer will confirm this. Your employer and you should be abiding by it in terms of pay and other benefits. If that is not happening you should complain immediately to your employer. If they don't immediately give you whatever money and benefits you are expecting, go see a lawyer.

However be aware that some benefits don't kick in for a few months. This should have been made clear to you in your offer. Read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Her Majesty's Government is generally pretty good at publishing your rights on stuff like this, and you can find very helpful official documentation [here](https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions/written-statement-of-employment-particulars).

This isn't talking about an employment contract, which is allowed to take longer. It is talking about a "statement of particulars" which is written information that must be provided on day 1 (and some which must be provided within 2 months.) Broadly speaking, it details your rights under the employment agreement: what you'll be paid and when, what holiday you can take, etc. Pension schemes can come into the 2 months follow on.

Again, the full contract can take longer, and it's not unusual for small companies (especially startups) to be slightly muddling their way around what running a company looks like. But it sounds like they have not just neglected to give you the contract, but have not provided this minimal information in writing. Of course "What you're doing is illegal" tends not to go down hugely well as a conversation opener, but there may still be a way to talk into "I know the whole lawyer thing is dragging on, but could I please get these things written down?" And if it helps open the conversation, As smci mentions, it's perfectly legitimate for you to provide a draft version based on your understanding of what you've been offered.

To conclude with a slight aside, your employment status is not dependent on having signed a contract. Your start date is the date that you started working, not the date you scribbled your initials on some paper. Their obligations to you as your employer (including mandatory pension contributions, but by no means limited to that) started when you started your employment. And when you get your employment contract, it will be backdated to when you actually started work. Obviously you should check, but they're also incentivised to make sure of it because claiming that the author of 6 months of their IP portfolio **wasn't working for them at the time** would be an idiotic thing to lie about in writing.

In summary,

- Know your rights, especially the rights you have by law.
- Do press for information, and to get such information in writing.
- Have confidence that they cannot make those rights go away just by not writing them down.

Answer (score 0):

Memo in writing the terms of contract they verbally agreed with you, and the date they verbally agreed. If they said "medical, pension and stock vesting start on day one", then say that. Include numbers and detail (how much pension? etc). Then you at least have a written agreement of what was agreed. Also document on your memo that they promised you a written employment contract to be signed on you first day. Have all your interactions with them in writing, preferably by certified mail.

At this point they're just playing you, and pocketing your $$$ premia and laughing at you. Maybe they will suddenly come up with a written contract if you quit (and maybe they won't), but it's your call whether to put up with that. You could quit, and if they then give you the written contract, ask (again, in writing) for retrospective payment for the period.

Comment: If they offer you a contract when you quit, you should keep walking out, because you already have an offer elsewhere.